# GWT - Google Web Toolkit - Client sends Payload Version 7, Server expects Version 4 [Serialization]

Tags: java, web, serialization, gwt, compilation

I have a GWT Project for a web application. I use Eclipse and the GWT Plugin 2.8.1. The issue is that when I compile and deploy to Tomcat 9.0 the client / Browser sends payloads of this format:

`7|0|6|http://s-sql2019:8080/PLTWEB6/|0CB98ABFD7B4B7FFCB9BD4179A20BC8B|com.zhh.pltwebtools.client.rpc.ServiceBenutzer|doServiceBenutzer_tblbenutzer_select|java.lang.String/2004016611|*|1|2|3|4|3|5|5|5|6|6|6|`

which is based on format for Version 7.

The Server gives back an error (500) and upon inspection it is because of the sent format. If you send the payload in this format:

`406http://s-sql2019:8080/PLTWEB6/95A90591D545B75749862669ED57F6E0com.zhh.pltwebtools.client.rpc.ServiceBenutzerdoServiceBenutzer_tblbenutzer_selectjava.lang.String*12343555666`

The Server reponds correctly. This is formatted in GWT's Version 4 format. Is there a way to upgrade the Serialization of the Server Side data to Version 7?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

I have installed the correct JRE runtime 1.8 for 64 and 32 bit versions. I have checked every lib to match and work with the specific other installed libs  (e.g. replace the gwt-servlet.jar with the correct version).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you post a "Minimal, Reproducible Example".  You can see how to do that from this guide; https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. In your case small pom with only essential dependencies, and 2 java classes for starting the project and sendng any simple message.

Comment: It is hard to reproduce since the GWT Project is from 2009. Code would not help since the .js is compiled by GWT and unreadable and the Serialilzation is not part of my Java code.The question is on purpose targeted at the issue of that the .js clientside serializes the data of the webform using Version 7 (visible because it starts with "7|0|6|http://s-" and the Server only works if you send it with version 4 Serialization format "406http://s-". The error is somewhere is the translation of the server from the received data to a Java Object.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this was [resolved in the gitter.im/gwtproject/gwt channel](https://matrix.to/#/!AvXTCxQwVkniJBaCEi:gitter.im/$x7yUqTXSYGd2JnCtuZ8Nfa6YzZ5zBNsE2joYNAd82Hs?via=gitter.im), but for completeness, here's the paraphrased answer:

As of [13 years ago](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/0fd2ee41f3b4b8228456efa2ed046df9638a9ba1/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/impl/AbstractSerializationStream.java#L52-L55), the minimum supported GWT-RPC version is `5`, so your server is somewhat older than that. Instead make sure you are using a copy of `gwt-servlet.jar` that matches your client-side code - ideally 2.8.1 since that is what your client is using, but any version released in the last decade or so should still work.